# Trouble in understanding the assumptions of paired difference tests

Tags: normal-distribution, t-test, paired-data

I have some difficulties in understanding the validity of the paired difference tests. Indeed, considering the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paired_difference_test) about that, it's written that

$${\rm var}(\bar{D})= \sigma_1^2/n + \sigma_2^2/n - 2\sigma_1\sigma_2\operatorname{corr}(Y_{i1}, Y_{i2})/n$$

with the additional justification that

> correlation is very common in the repeated measures setting, since many factors influencing the value being compared are unaffected by the treatment.

which indeed makes sense otherwise the paired test would be somehow useless.

Why would the random variable $\bar{D}=\bar{Y_2}-\bar{Y_1}$ follow a distribution $N(0, \sqrt{(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)/n})$ ?

First, where did the covariance disappear (since it's not likely to be $0$) and hence, why should we consider that the difference of two normal variables is normal as well ?

I did not get these points, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: As an aside, it’s useful too generalize paired comparisons by using a model.  There are models for doing both parametric (paired $t$-test) and nonparametric (rank difference test as a superior replacement of the Wilcoxon signed-rank test) as discussed [here](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/nonpar).

Answer (score 5):

You'll notice that that formula appears right after the words "The **unpaired** Z-test statistic is.." (emphasis mine).

A bit further down on the page the first expression including covariance - now as its square root and called $S$ - does appear in the denominator of the paired test.

The article is a bit confusing in that it dives straight into a comparison versus the unpaired test without showing a paired test, and it uses $S$ for 'the standard deviation' in both the unpaired and paired version. The difference between two normal random variables is also normal, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917276/distribution-of-the-difference-of-two-normal-random-variables).

Comment: "The difference between two normal random variables is also normal" well only if they are independent... which is precisely my main question . So your answer is clearly not convincing...

Comment: No, this still holds if they are not independent, obviously the (co)variance will differ for the dependent case. See e.g. [here](https://srabbani.com/bivariate.pdf). In the worst case there is always the CLT.